# Controlling QR Code Scanning Actions

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, qr-code

I am looking to create a QR code that does the following:

1. When scanned from inside an application, it dislpays a custom alert, (Ex. "You won $5")
2. When scanned with a different QR code reader (non app) it goes to a mobile web page that directs the user to download the application.

My main question is: Can you control what happens when a QR code is scanned by a reader that is not your own? (A 'default' action, if you will)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hash to your URL (http://foo.com/index.html#You won $5!, where everything past the # is the hash) and look for the hash. You could also prefix the hash with something that you know, then remove the prefix when you display the alert view. In a standard QR reader it would just open the website ignoring the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You want to register an intent for the URL.

For example, assume the QR contains the following URL

```
http://m.example.com/12345
```

If your app scans it, it recognises that it's a valid URL for your service (because it contains your domain). It then looks up the code (12345) from it's database and sees that it contains "You won £5" or whatever.

If a regular scanner reads the code, it will visit your mobile website - you can then redirect them to the app store for their device.

Answer (score 0):

Use qr-zbar-ane native extension and code it to make what you want after reading the QR Code. You can find samples and extension download at : http://www.nativext.com/ane-by-os/ios/qr-reader-native-extension/

And use this code to navigate to the URL which you scanned :

```
protected function scannedHandler( event : QRZBarEvent ) : void {
    qr.removeEventListener( QRZBarEvent.SCANNED, scannedHandler );
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(event.result));
}
```